# Select value randomly from groups of values of different types

Tags: c++

I have arrays of types int, bool and float:

```
std::array<int, 3>myInts = {15, 3, 6};
std::array<bool, 2>myBools = {true, false};
std::array<float,5>myFloats = {0.1, 15.2, 100.6, 10.44, 5.5};
```

I would like to generate a random integer(I know how to do that) from 0 to the total number of elements (3 + 2 + 5) so the generated random Integer represents one of the values. Next based on that integer I would like to retrieve my value and do further calculations with it. The problem I am facing is that I don't want to use `if else` statements like these:

```
int randInt = RandIntGen(0, myInts.size() + myBools.size() + myFloats.size());//Generates a random Integer

if(randInt<myInts.size()){//if the random integer is less than the size of the integers array I can choose
                         // from the the integers array
   int myValue = myInts[RandInt]
}
else if(randInt>=myInts.size() && randInt<myBools.size() + myInts.size()){//if the random integer 
//is between the size o the integer's array and the size of the bool's array + the size of the integers array 
//then I can choose from the bool's array   
   bool myValue = myBools(RandInt - myInts.size())
}
. 
.
.
```

Then if for example  `randInt=2` then `myValue=6` or if `randInt=4` then `myValue=false`

However I would like that the selection algorithm was more straightforward something like:

```
int randInt = RandIntGen(0, myInts.size() + myBools.size() + myFloats.size());

allValues = {myInts, myBools, myFloats}
if(type_id(allValues[randInt]).name=="int")
  int myValue = allValues[randInt] //(this value will be used for further calculations)
if(type_id(allValues[randInt]).name=="bool")
  bool myValue = allValues[randInt] //(this value will be used for further calculations)
```

I've tried with a mix of templates, inheritance and linked lists however I cannot implement what I want. I think the solution should be really simple but at this time I cannot think of something else.

I am novice in C++ I've been learning already for 1 and half months, before I was doing stuff in python and everything was way easier but then I decided to try C++. I am not a experienced programmer I know some basic things and I am trying to learn new things, thanks for the help.

Comment: How would you use the value if you don't know what type it has? How do you "do further calculations" with `bool` value?

Comment: What is the overall objective? Knowing your further calculations or the reason for them might lead to someone suggesting a better strategy than having a container that effectively has integers, Booleans, and floats mixed together. It's possible that you can just use a container of floats where integers would become whole number floats and any number other than zero will become true else false.

Comment: If you want something like this, you could create a wrapper base class `Number` that has a `typeName` method that returns `"bool"`, `"float"`, or `"int"`. You could then use a method `void* getValue()` and, based on the value of `typeName`, cast to a pointer of the appropriate type.

Comment: Sorry for not answering but my computer just broke after I post the question and I have been trying to repair it.

Comment: Sorry for not answering but my computer just broke after I post the question and I have been trying to repair it. I want to make a simple genetic programming program, so i started with selecting random data types for my functions. I know it sounds weird but that's how I think the algorithm works.

Comment: For creating the functions I store pointers to a function  in objects that are class templates with the type of the arguments and the return type as parameters  of the template, this works as long as I don't mix different templates types in the same array but if I want to apply the selection algorithm that i explained before I cannot avoid the use of `if` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably, you need to think how to satisfy your requirements in a simpler way, but it is possible to get literally what you want with C++17. If your compiler doesn't support C++17, you can use corresponding boost libraries. Here is the code:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <variant>

using Result = std::variant<int, bool, float>;

template<class T>
bool take_impl(int& i, const T& vec, Result& result)
{
    if (i < static_cast<int>(std::size(vec)))
        result = vec[i];
    i -= std::size(vec);
    return i < 0;
}

template<class T>
Result take(int i, const T& arrays)
{
    if (i < 0)
        throw std::runtime_error("i is too small");
    Result res;
    std::apply([&i, &res](const auto&... array) { return (take_impl(i, array, res) || ...); }, arrays);
    if (i >= 0)
        throw std::runtime_error("i is too large");
    return res;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const Result& v)
{
    if (std::holds_alternative<int>(v))
        std::cout << "int(" << std::get<int>(v);
    else if (std::holds_alternative<bool>(v))
        std::cout << "bool(" << std::get<bool>(v);
    else
        std::cout << "float(" << std::get<float>(v);
    return std::cout << ')';
}

auto arrays = std::make_tuple(
    std::array<int, 3>{15, 3, 6},
    std::array<bool, 2>{true, false},
    std::array<float,5>{0.1, 15.2, 100.6, 10.44, 5.5}
);

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << take(i, arrays) << '\n';
}
```

If you are not required to keep separate arrays of different types, you can make one uniform array of `std::variant<int, bool, float>`. This will be significantly more efficient than using `std::shared_ptr`-s.